# How to put fine grid in plot

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a function like this:

```
plot(f,Body, 'r', f,Walk, 'b', 'LineWidth' , 3);
```

I want to put fine grid in the plot. How do I do this.

Tried this

```
plot(f,Body, 'r', f,Walk, 'b', 'LineWidth' , 3);

 GridVisible = TRUE,
 SubgridVisible = TRUE;
```

but failed.

Answer (score 3):

try to add after your plot line either

```
grid on
```

or ,

```
grid minor
```

To add labels get the positions of the minor grid ticks using the   `XMinorTick` , `YMinorTick` properties, and add them as labels using the `XTickLabel` , `YTickLabel` properties. See more in [Matlab documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes_props.html).

Comment: That worked, but its not labeling all the grid lines intersecting with x and y axis.

Comment: you've asked for a "fine grid" not grid labels. Besides labeled minor grid ticks what else do you ask for? please update the question accordingly.

Comment: @gpuguy Do you want `xlabel(gca, 'Time/s'); ylabel(gca, 'Energy/J');`, for instance?

Comment: Or use both of them